# Websocket Testing [Functional]

Tags: php, testing, websocket, phpunit, ratchet

I am using Ratchet for websockets in PHP. I was able to write unit (phpspec) and acceptance tests (behat) for websockets but I cannot find a way on how to test the connection to the websocket server by using a functional phpunit test.. I think a test, which checks if the connection is up and running, would be very important. I thought of something like the following:

1. Create a (ratchet) client in phpunit
2. Connect to ws url (e.g. client->connect(host, port, ...)
3. ping websocket / send / receive some messages (call methods of client, e.g. client->push(..)..)

The problem is, that I don't know which class is responsible for establishing the connection (creating a client which can request the websocket) in Ratchet and how a test would then look like. How can I create a Ratchet Client in order to be able to connect and request a websocket in phpunit functional test? (similar to e.g. a webclient within a standard phpunit functional test)

As an example, within a functional test for a feature, I could do the following:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->request('GET', '/book/3', array(), array(), array('HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'));
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertEquals(
    440,
    $response->getStatusCode()
);
```

Or e.g. create an authenticated client instead of an anonymous. How would it be possible, to "translate" this functional test into a ratchet websocket one?

Comment: So you downvote the question, but as I can see, when I google for websocket functional test, this is one of very few pages that shows up on the results. I will clarify my question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this partially solves your question of what part of the Ratchet Websocket is responsible of making a connection.

The test itself will probably not work, I am not that experienced with testing in PHP although it should put you on the right path.

```
public function testCanConnect()
    {
        \Ratchet\Client\connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8080')->then(function($conn) {
            $conn->on('message', function($msg) use ($conn) {
                print $msg."\n";
                $this->assertEquals('true',true);
                $this->assertEquals("Hello World",$msg);
                $conn->close();
            });
            $conn->send('Hello World!');
        }, function ($e) {
            echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        });
    }
```

If you have any further questions please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. So this is the "pendant" on server side to the autobahnjs client side framework I am using to establish the connection.

Comment: I have to warn you that the PHPUnit code is not working probably since I enver wrote a single UnitTest in PHPUnit before.
Since you seem more experienced with it, this should put you on the right track.

Comment: Yes thats allright, I know how to write phpunit I just did not know the ratchet server side part. That was the missing piece. Extra: When writing a test where you connect to something, it's normally a functional test. But still, I can write it with phpunit and know how to :)

Comment: If you finished the test so that it is working, could yous end it back to me so that I can change the answer for other people that run into the same problem?

Comment: I will then probably update the question, but I think your answer is enough for everyone having the same problem.

Comment: any idea on how to authenticate the user? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547276/php-websocket-test-authentication